# What is the problem with this query? I am trying to create a practice small table with some primary id to do matching but I don't find the error here

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1241

Small table to practice id matching.

```
CREATE DATABASE test_1;
USE test_1;

CREATE TABLE test_items(

contact_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR (20) ,
last_name VARCHAR (20),
PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
);

INSERT INTO test_items()

VALUES (
(NULL, 'Javier','Droid'),
(NULL,'Gret','Jun'),
(null,'Kilot','Ramirez')

);
SELECT * FROM test_items;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO test_items() - you don't need the braces but if you use them you must specify columns.And you don't need the first opening  brace after the values clause or its closing brace

Answer (score 1):

Always specify the column names you are inserting:

```
INSERT INTO test_items(first_name, last_name)  
VALUES ('Javier','Droid'), ('Gret','Jun'), ('Kilot','Ramirez'); 

SELECT * FROM test_items;
```